# Issue with a Post Request with fetch : Uncaught (in promise) typeError: NetworkError when attempting to fetch resource

Tags: javascript, forms, post, fetch, typeerror

Im encountering some troubles with a simple fetch and a post request (simple but my first).
In the cart page of my site, Im trying to send data to the server after the click on the order bouton. to be able to send anything, the client have to fill a form with his intire name, address, city and email.
So after the validation process, two things are about to be send:

- an object contact with all the informations from the client
- an array products, with (for now) only the different id of the different items purchased.

My troubles seem to be bound with my form. When I launch my event by clicking on the button, I encounter an error: Uncaught (in promise) typeError: NetworkError when attempting to fetch resource.

I looked after this on internet but Im not sure I understood it well.

HTTP

```
<form class="cart__order__form">
                
                <div class="cart__order__form__question">
                  <label for="firstName">Prénom: </label>
                  <input type="text" name="firstName" id="firstName" required>
                  <p id="firstNameErrorMsg"><!-- ci est un message d'erreur --></p>
                </div>
                
                <div class="cart__order__form__question">
                  <label for="lastName">Nom: </label>
                  <input type="text" name="lastName" id="lastName" required>
                  <p id="lastNameErrorMsg"></p>
                </div>
                
                <div class="cart__order__form__question">
                  <label for="address">Adresse: </label>
                  <input type="text" name="address" id="address" required>
                  <p id="addressErrorMsg"></p>
                </div>
                
                <div class="cart__order__form__question">
                  <label for="city">Ville: </label>
                  <input type="text" name="city" id="city" required>
                  <p id="cityErrorMsg"></p>
                </div>
                
                <div class="cart__order__form__question">
                  <label for="email">Email: </label>
                  <input type="email" name="email" id="email" required>
                  <p id="emailErrorMsg"></p>
                </div>
                
                <div class="cart__order__form__submit">
                  <input type="submit" value="Commander !" id="order">
                  <input type="reset" value="Réinitialiser" id="reset">
                </div>
              </form>
```

JS

```
submitValidation.addEventListener('click',  (e)=>{
            // COnfiguration des regEx pour la validation 

            let nameRegEx= /^[a-zA-ZéèîïÉÈÊÎÏ][a-zéèêàçîïüöô]+([-'\s][a-zA-ZéèîïÉÈÎÏ]+)?/;
            let mailRegEx= /(([^<>()\[\]\\.,;:\s@"]+(\.[^<>()\[\]\\.,;:\s@"]+)*)|(".+"))@((\[[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}])|(([a-zA-Z\-0-9]+\.)+[a-zA-Z]{2,}))/;
            let localisationRegEx= /^[a-zA-Z0-9éèîïÉÈÊÎÏ] [a-zéèêàçîïüöô]+([-'\s][a-zA-ZéèîïÉÈÎÏ]+)?/; ;
            let noProblem=true;
            
                    // fonction de validition et d'envoi des valeurs des input. 
                formInputs.forEach(function(el){
                  let errorMsg=document.getElementById(`${el.id}ErrorMsg`);  
                  
    
                if (el.validity.valueMissing){
                    e.preventDefault();   
                    errorMsg.innerText='Donnée Manquante';
                    errorMsg.style.color="red";
                    noProblem= false;
                }
                else {
                  switch (el.id){
                    case 'firstName':
                        if (nameRegEx.test(firstName.value)==false){
                            e.preventDefault();
                            firstNameError.innerText='Format incorrect';
                            firstNameError.style.color="orange";
                            noProblem= false;
                        };
                        break;
                    
                    case 'lastName':
                        if(nameRegEx.test(lastName.value)==false){
                            e.preventDefault();
                            lastNameError.innerText='Format incorrect';
                            lastNameError.style.color="orange";
                            noProblem= false;    
                        };
                        break;
                    
                    case 'email':
                        if (mailRegEx.test(email.value)==false){
                            e.preventDefault();
                            emailError.innerText='Format incorrect';
                            emailError.style.color="orange";
                            noProblem= false;
                        };
                        break;
                  }}  
            });

// Préparation des variables contenant les données à envoyer.
    //Données liées aux articles de la commande 
    // Id from the Items in the cart, soon to be purchased
            cart.forEach(function(el){
                    products.push(el.id);
                });
    // Données liées aux informations acheteurs
    // Buyers informations
            contact={"firstName":firstName.value,
                    "lastName":lastName.value,
                    "address":address.value,
                    "city":city.value,
                    "email":email.value};

let sendToServer={contact, products};

// Configuration des routes post
// post request
    let response=  fetch('http://localhost:3000/api/products/order', {
        method: 'POST',
        headers:{'Content-Type':'application/json'},
        body: JSON.stringify(sendToServer)
    });
    // let result= await response.json();
 });
```

[When I click on my submit button and the inputs are all filled as they should be. I will a typeError: NetworkError when attempting to fetch resource looking like this that](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PSbrx.png)

[But when I miss one input field, I will have this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/322pL.png)

Iam still apprehanding the fetch function, and I know I have still a lot to understand, but it's pretty difficult for me to get of to resolve the typeError.

Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 0):

`fetch` requests return a promise which is [rejected with a TypeError](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Fetch_API/Using_Fetch#checking_that_the_fetch_was_successful) if a network error occurs.

Since there is no error handling for `response` being rejected, promise handling will generate an `uncaught in promise` error. The solution to the omission is to add error handling for a rejected `fetch` that handles the error according to business needs of the site.

The network error  itself usually means that the URL could not be reached because the server is down or the url is incorrect. It should have little to nothing to do with validation of the form data, except that if `noProblem` is false, `fetch` is probably not being called.

There could be a typo in the port number of the fetch URL: the image of the error posted shows the browser attempted to load `favicon.ico` from port 5500, suggesting the HTML page was loaded from port 5500, in turn suggesting that the post should also be using port 5500. Whatever the reason turns out to be, there is no server currently responding to the fetch request on port 3000.